# When I try adding a new site to iis it says it already exists. This is the first site I'm trying to add

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, iis-8

When I try adding a new site to iis 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 it says it already exists. This is the first site I'm trying to add. I am not finding where this site may or may not exist.

Essentially what I am trying to do is copy my websites to a new web server. The web servers are both in Azure on VM's. Endpoints are set and static IP is set. There is one site, that when I try to create it, it errors out and informs me that it already exists.

Comment: Does it happen when you try to create any site, or is it a name you've somehow used before in a different capacity? Have you tried creating a site with a totally different name just to see if it lets you create sites at all?

Comment: It is only the site with a certain name. It is running on another server. I was able to add the other sites. Now when I enter the IP address of the new server it is redirecting to the other server. I can't find the file(s) where this may be configured.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities (I'll edit this to follow up if need be)

- Some stuff in Azure is global, so if your two VMs are in the same resource group, the site may already exist. Or the VHD for your new server may be in the same storage account as the old one?
- You may also be impacted by a recent service outage that is messing up a few things. If it's letting you create other sites that already exist, but not that one, wait a little while and then submit a support ticket about the bug with your missing site.

Comment: I need to access the new web server via IP address so I can test it before switching over from previous one.

Comment: You should still be able to do that just to make sure it's running, but ping has weird behavior on Azure. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/

Comment: Now localhost is serving me the other servers content. Must be bindings in Azure maybe.

Comment: Check and see if the VMS are on the same resource group, storage account, what's shared between them.